# slow image encryption/decryption on Android

Tags: java, php, android, encryption, cryptography

I have already implemented encryption/decryption between php and android using AES/CBC.

However, when I decrypt images using android phone, it will always take more than 1 second for a 300k file. How can I speed up the decryption? Thank you very much!

**PS:** I am using `mCrypt extension` for php encryption and `javax.crypto.Cipher` for android decryption.
I mean can I use other cryto or other mode?

Comment: Why don't you just use transport encryption (eg. HTTPS)? What's the purpose of encrypting it?

Comment: Encryption is used to ensure that users is only able to view these images in my App. There is also download function in my app, so if images are not encrypted users can use file explorer to view them.

Comment: @jreuab,this question does not provide an alternative encryption way.

Comment: There is no alternative way. Android encryption is simply slow, as was already discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569286/android-file-decrytion-and-encrytion-taking-time, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282930/android-slow-aes-decryption, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257945/aes-decryption-on-android-too-slow-to-be-usable-will-ndk-be-faster-other-ideas, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619770/android-aes-encryption-decryption, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713166/speed-up-encryption-decryption.

Comment: @vincentzhou I don't think there is one using the Dalvik VM.

Comment: By the way: you know that decompiling your app and getting the key would be really easy? I don't think this adds any extra security.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin, It will also not help if I use RC4 instead?

Comment: If you contemplate choosing speed over security you are doing it wrong. Better to do not encrypt (no security but the best speed) at all instead of using known weak cipher (weak or no security AND speed penalty).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33171612/475496 This example helped me speedup encryption, maybe this helps you to.